# Why does fargate default infrastructure involve one VPC and two subnets?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I would like to know what the underlying reasons why these resources are necessary. Specially curious about the two subnets requirement.

Even official AWS cloudformation templates for fargate setups do include these resources.

Comment: I really don't get why the vpc and subnets in particular have to be specified every time a task is run instead of just being part of the task definition like everything else...it would be nice to at least have defaults on the task definition that you can override

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By providing two subnets you are actually providing two availability zones. It's a standard practice for AWS to distribute resources across AZs for high availability in case one zone would go under. A single subnet can not spread across two or more zones, therefore you are required to provide two.

Fargates requires ["Availability Zone Spread" placement strategy](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/amazon-ecs-availability-best-practices/) and by specifying subnets you implicitly specifying different AZs.

Answer (score 1):

If you create more than one subnet in a VPC, the CIDR blocks of the subnets cannot overlap. For example, if you create a VPC with CIDR block 10.0. 0.0/24, it supports 256 IP addresses.

You can break this CIDR block into two subnets, each supporting 128 IP addresses.

**refer:*https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Subnets.html*

Answer (score 1):

Fargate will always try to span the tasks across the available AZ's in the VPC specified. Task placement strategies is an algorithm that can help you choose how to place the tasks and is on best effort basis only. However, Task placement strategies are not supported for tasks using the Fargate launch type. By default, Fargate tasks are spread across Availability Zones [1].

---

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-placement.html